# AWS EC2 Bitbucket Pipeline is not executing the latest code deployed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, bitbucket-pipelines

I've followed all the steps of implementing the Bitbucket pipeline in order to have continuous development in AWS EC2. I've used the Code Deploy Application tool together with all configuration that needs to be done in AWS. I'm using EC2, Ubuntu and I'm trying to deploy a MEAN app.

As per bitbucket, I've added variables under "Repository variables" including:

- S3_BUCKET
- DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME
- DEPLOYMENT_CONFIG
- AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
- AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
- AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

and also I've added three required files:

**codedeploy_deploy.py** -  that I've got from this link: https://bitbucket.org/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-bitbucket-pipelines-python/src/73b7c31b0a72a038ea0a9b46e457392c45ce76da/codedeploy_deploy.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

**appspec.yml** -

```
  version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/aok
permissions:
  - object: /home/ubuntu/aok
    owner: ubuntu
    group: ubuntu
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: scripts/install_dependencies
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
    - location: scripts/start_server
      timeout: 300
      runas: root

 3. **bitbucket-pipelines.yml**



    mage: node:10.15.1

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-dev
          - curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
          - python get-pip.py
          - pip install awscli
          - python codedeploy_deploy.py
          - aws deploy push --application-name $APPLICATION_NAME --s3-location s3://$S3_BUCKET/aok.zip --ignore-hidden-files
          - aws deploy create-deployment --application-name $APPLICATION_NAME --s3-location bucket=$S3_BUCKET,key=aok.zip,bundleType=zip --deployment-group-name $DEPLOYMENT_GROUP_NAME
```

On the Pipeline tab on Bitbucket when I am pushing the code is showing the Successful message and also in S3 when I am downloading the latest version, the changes that I pushed are there. The problem is the website is not showing the new changes, there is still the initial version that I cloned before implementing the PIPELINE.

Comment: What website did you mention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `codedeploy_deploy.py` script is not supported anymore. The recommended way is to migrate from the CodeDeploy addon to [aws-code-deploy](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/aws-code-deploy) Bitbucket Pipe. There is a deployment guide from Atlassian that will help you to get started with the pipe: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-aws-with-codedeploy-976773337.html

Comment: @alexabder-zhuokov I configured with the link suggested and now I am having an error on bitbucket when the pipeline is deploying. Error is like this:


INFO: Deployment created with id d-H2MXWT2Z0.
INFO: Waiting for deployment to complete.
aws deploy wait deployment-successful --deployment-id d-H2MXWT2Z0
ERROR: Deployment failed. Fetching deployment information... 
aws deploy get-deployment --deployment-id d-H2MXWT2Z0

Comment: You should inspect your deployment (d-H2MXWT2Z0) in the AWS console to see if there are any issues with your deployment group. Maybe there are IAM permissions missing or you don't have enough healthy instances